# Gatsby Head API not properly formatting scripts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm trying to use [Gatsby's Head API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-head/) with Gatsby.js (4.24.2) and TypeScript and I'm getting some mixed results.

Here's what I have, it works but certain scripts fail to compile:

```
const Page = ({ location }) => {
   // code
   return ( ... )
}

export const Head = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Example</title>
      <script>console.log("hello")</script>
    </>    
  )
}
```

This works, it changes the title of the page to "Example" and my console log is sent.  In VS Code it doesn't look like it is formatting the console log statement correctly, but it works regardless:

[image]

(it looks like plain text instead of formatted JavaScript)

However, when I try to add a new custom javascript function to the `Head` like this, Gatsby does not compile and VS Code highlights everything with red, it seems like it does not know I'm trying to declare a function.

```
    <>
      <title>Example</title>
      <script>console.log("hello")</script>
      <script>(function(w, d, s) { ... script contents })(w,d,s);</script>
    </>
```

Thanks. Can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the formatting was different but I managed to create a workaround that compiles, like this:

```
export const Head = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
          console.log("This is the test, and you passed!");
          (function(w, d, s) { ... script code ... })(w, d, s);
        `
      }}/>
    </>
  )
}
```